# C# MVC bing TextArea to String instead of String[]

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC app where I use templates for the EditorFor.

The thing is that in some string properties I have to render TextArea, but it doesn't bind back on post since TextArea posts as string[].

Is there a quick and dirty way to work around this?

The Control Template is:

```
<@model string
<textarea class="form-control" id="@ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId("")" name="@ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName("")" placeholder="@ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Key=="UIWatermark").Value" rows="3">@Model </textarea>
```

Comment: can you show the model and view?

Comment: It's irrelevant. It's basically a string. TextArea is rendered with string using the template.

Comment: you really should NOT be doing any logic in your view:
```placeholder="@ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Key=="UIWatermark").Value"``` is not ideal

Comment: Not ideal, but at the moment, required. It's in order to handle custom property attributes. Not relevant for my problem :)

The issue is that the TextArea is not binding back to the string property. If I change the property to string[] it does work, but I rather not so, is there any way to bind TextArea as string on post instead of string[]?